# Trigger.io - perform application logic before view is displayed

Tags: android, ios, trigger.io

I am one day into using trigger.io to develop apps and have run into a little trouble. My app requires that the user log in when first launching, upon successful log-in their user settings are stored using `forge.prefs.set`. The log-in form is index.html - thus loaded first when the app is launched.

After the user has logged in, I check to see if they have already logged in by checking for their userID with `forge.prefs.get`. If they are logged in, I redirect them to the main page of the app -

```
forge.prefs.get('user', function(result) {
    if (result) {
        window.location.href = 'main.html'; // They're logged in, redirect
    }
});


 $(function () {
... main app logic
});
```

However, this approach causes the login form to be visible for a split second before the code checking to see if they are already logged in runs.

I noticed this in docs for the trigger.io module launchimage:
`By default, the launch image is hidden automatically when the window load event fires or after 5 seconds, whichever is sooner.`

It sounds like I want to run this check during the "window load event," but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that - Google and searching the docs did not turn anything up.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is set the [launchimage to hide manually](https://trigger.io/modules/launchimage/current/docs/index.html) and make sure its never hidden before your check is complete.

In config for your launchimage module:

```
"hide-manually": true
```

In your code:

```
forge.prefs.get('user', function(result) {
  if (result) {
    window.location.href = 'main.html'; // They're logged in, redirect
  }
  forge.launchimage.hide(); // hide launch image after check is finished
});
```

Comment: Ahh, this looks promising. I went to install the `launchimage` module and discovered it is a premium feature - I'm just in the 14 day trial at the moment. Does this basically mean that the Forge launch screen is there unless you're a paid subscriber and install the module?

Comment: Oh right, launchimage is a premium module. If you want to stay on the free plan, you could also initially show a loading indicator in your index.html and switch to login/main as soon as the prefs check is done. This way users wouldn't see the login form before being redirected.

Comment: Thanks :) Another trigger.io question that you might be able to answer coming up in a second....

Comment: Here's my latest question, Patrick - any help would be appreciated. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342232/trigger-io-request-times-out